# jQuery addClass to various different Divs

Tags: jquery

My problem seems fairly simple but I don't know the solution.

I have a number of divs with different ID's. I want to use jQuery to add a class to all of these different divs. Of course I can write out a new line of jQuery for each div and use .addClass but I was wondering if there was a way to bunch it all together. Something like:

```
$('#menu-item-450','#menu-item-451','#menu-item-452','#menu-item-453','#menu-item-454').find('a').addClass('btn-green');
```

Thanks

Comment: Give them all a common class

Comment: Post the HTML structure of your divs and explain which divs you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use it like you use in CSS. After all they're all css selectors.

```
$('#menu-item-450, #menu-item-451, #menu-item-452, #menu-item-453, #menu-item-454').find('a').addClass('btn-green');
```

Comment: Obviously! Thanks for this, I think I had a mental block or something.

Answer (score 1):

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`^` [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with 
a value beginning exactly with a given string.
```

**js**

```
$('div[id^=menu-item]').find('a').addClass('btn-green');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as there are other items on the page with ID's starting with #menu-item that I don't want to affect.

Comment: @DesignSubway check updated code `$('div[id^="menu-item"]').find('a').addClass('btn-green');`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the `#menu-item-x` and then just say `$(".CLASS_NAME").find("a").addClass("btn-green")`

Answer (score 0):

If all your div id's starts with menu-item-, you can use starts with selector:

```
$("div[id^='menu-item-s']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all divs with "menu-item-" like this:

```
$('div[id^="menu-item-"]')
```

Then just add the rest:

```
$('div[id^="menu-item-"]').find('a').addClass('btn-green');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find div by first text

```
$("div[id^='menu-item-']").find('a').addClass('class');
```